# Lauterbach cmm scripts v <Myfunc> is not working

Tags: powerpc, trace32, lauterbach

I am trying to invoke the function () from cmm scripts during my CPU is running state or Halted state.
the command i used here is

```
    v <myfunc> or
    Var.Call <myfunc> or
    Var.Set <myfunc>
```

once i executed this command none of the above listed is working in my environment.

CPU : power PC (MPC5500)
Thanks,
KPS

Comment: It should work like that. Maybe your version of TRACE32 is too old? It might help if you would post the declaration of the C function you'd like to call, and you could also post the exact TRACE32 command (with arguments).

Comment: CPU must be halted to invoke a function from the debugger.

Comment: Hello Holger, Thanks for your information. inside < myfunc> has the illegal opcode so during execution the function control goes to stack corruption or halted in somewhere.